# Programmatically login to http://login.live.com

Tags: php, symfony, automation, ui-automation, goutte

As part of a testing automation project, I need to be able to login to http://login.live.com

Is that possible? I am currently using Symfony and Goutte

Comment: Do you want to programmatically control a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Live support Oauth2 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx

There are plenty of Oauth2 client written in PHP.